# When brew installing opencv3 I get warning that formula has no --with-contrib option

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

My intent is to install opencv for use with C++ on macOs 10.12.6 (16G29). It seems the suggested method is using homebrew to install.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

I used this command to install:

brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --c++11

and everything finished without error but I received the following warnings:

Warning: opencv: this formula has no --c++11 option so it will be ignored!
Warning: opencv: this formula has no --with-contrib option so it will be ignored!

From brew info opencv3:

$ brew info opencv3
opencv: stable 3.3.1 (bottled)
Open source computer vision library
https://opencv.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1 (519 files, 95.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-11-21 at 08:11:10
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/opencv.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘, pkg-config ✘
Required: eigen ✔, ffmpeg ✔, jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, libtiff ✔, openexr ✔, numpy ✔, tbb ✔
==> Requirements
Required: python ✔, python3 ✔

Has anyone had success installing opencv3 for c++ development on macOs?

Comment: I got it working compiling from source on MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042674/1602316

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. Take a look at the output of "brew info opencv". It turns out that the opencv was moved to homebrew-core:

```
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/opencv.rb
```

To show the list of available '--with-*' options allowed to be passed to homebrew during an install, use:

```
brew options opencv
```

I would assume that it returns nothing, since the formula does not define any such options anymore.

**Installing Opencv**

If you have not installed opencv, install with:

```
brew install opencv
```

This should just install from source by downloading and compiling opencv with the packages listed in the homebrew formula. Since there are currently no options in the opencv formula, passing in something like --with-*, for example --with-contrib, will not be recognized as a valid option. However the formula actually happens to install certain things like contrib by default now.

If you already have opencv installed, try reinstalling:

```
brew reinstall opencv
```

This will reinstall from source as well.

(Fyi, recompile takes about 10-20 minutes)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your explanation. How does brew reinstall fix the problem?

Comment: Updated the post, if you dont have it installed yet, install with 'brew install opencv'. They updated the formula so now it does not support any options. see: 'brew options opencv'. as an example, you can try 'brew options python' to see what it would normally give you